# using datapager in asp.net consum almost whole of bandwidth between SQL server and IIS server what should I do?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datapager

I have a table with 40000+ records in it, the total size of this table is something around 50Mb. I have an asp.net website in which I use a datapager and a listview. In each page I show only 10 records.

Whenever I click on next/prev button on the datapager, I can see that the whole data table from the SQL Server is uploaded to IIS Server (using performance monitor)

How can I prevent this situation? Does it mean ms datapager is not practical? Is there any alternative? Or is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: *Please avoid duplicating your questions* try to delete your other post

Comment: *Exact* duplicate of [using datapager in asp.net consum almost whole of bandwidth between SQL server and IIS server what should I do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935939/using-datapager-in-asp-net-consum-almost-whole-of-bandwidth-between-sql-server-an)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to implement is [custom paging](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/efficiently-paging-through-large-amounts-of-data-cs).

> Custom Paging improves the performance of default paging by retrieving only those records from the database that need to be displayed for the particular page of data requested by the user; however, custom paging involves a bit more effort to implement than default paging

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are not utilizing paging mechanism for ASP.net data sources. Of cause it not practical at all, to send 40K+ records by wire. You have to page data, size of page ~500 records.

With our code/configuration it not possible to answer that, but definately you have a bug there.